# Working with big multidimensional arrays in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, out-of-memory, bigdata

I have 260 GB of data from an agent-based *NetLogo* simulation. The data has already been prepared in a way, that it can be used efficiently for visualisation and analysis. The data is currently split into .mat files, each containing a 4-dimensional array, with the size of

```
270 x 2502 x 9 x 50
```

When loaded, one array uses 2.26 GB of memory. This takes about 5 seconds. In total, there are more than 100 files. Up until now, my approach was to loop over the .mat files, use `load`, use the data (e.g. draw a curve), use `clearvars` and continue with the next file.

Needless to say, this is a naive approach that takes too much time. `datastore` is not an option, since I have 4-dimensional data and .mat files. Is there another way to deal with this situation more effectively? Most of the time I only use a small set of these arrays, e.g. one dimension fixed:

```
A(:, :, 1, :)
```

Comment: [`memmapfile`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/memmapfile.html) maybe? Though you'd still need to find a way to create the file without running out of RAM.

Comment: How about saving the data to a raw binary file (instead of `mat` file), then you could read just the portion you need using `fread` and `fseek`. You can write a wrapper to help you load just the dimension(s) you need.

Comment: have a look at hdf5 file format, sometimes works very good for big data.

Comment: @AnderBiguri .mat IS hdf5

Comment: @HennadiiMadan really? didnt know. I assumed it was not due to the fact that https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hdf5read.html exists.

Comment: @AnderBiguri .mat is a set of conventions on organization of HDF5 storage ,and therefore is a "subset" of HDF5. HDF5 is more general. That's why two sets of functions. If you are interested in details here you can find the exact conventions being used https://pythonhosted.org/hdf5storage/information.html

Comment: @HennadiiMadan thank that very interesting indeed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [matfile](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matfile.html) function to load subsets of a matfile into memory without loading the entire file. Since .mat is a subset of HDF5 format for most of the purposes their usage is (almost) equivalent. However due to matlab devs' madskills and also depending on your workflow it is not guaranteed to be faster than whatever you are doing now.

Comment: @HennadiiMedan As you said, this is not the fastest solution, but more conventient than what was suggested in the comments for my question.